# EF Core DBContext caching results

Tags: c#, .net, api, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a .net core API that includes a data layer where all the data retrieval and manipulation occurs. The DB context is injected in Startup and repo classes all inherit from a base repo class where the db context is passed in. In one particular method, I have to loop through records and get their related entities that match certain criteria. I noticed that on the second round of the loop, the related entities from previous loop is returned even though they don't meet the filter criteria and also the sql query that gets generated returns correct number of records when executed directly on the server. To illustrate what's happening here are the details:

Entity: Unit (each unit has two UnitPropertyA and two UnitPropertyB under two different languages respectively)

Related entity: UnitPropertyA

Related entity: UnitPropertyB

My code to retrieve the Unit and its related entities filtered by languageId is as follows

(start looping in the business layer for each languageId by calling the following method in the repo):

```
public async Task<Unit> GetUnitByLangIdAsync(int Id, int langId)
{

       var result = await _context.Unit
        .Where(x => x.UnitId == Id)
        .Include(x => x.UnitPropertyA.Where(i => i.LanguageId == langId).OrderByDescending(i => i.Id)).Take(1)
        .Include(x => x.UnitPropertyB.Where(i => i.LanguageId == langId).OrderByDescending(i => i.Id)).Take(1)                      
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        return result;(result returned to the business layer)
}
(...end loop in the business layer)
```

I noticed that this would give me correct result for the first language and the result for the second language would include records from the previous iteration(i.e. the first language). Did I miss anything?
Any hint is appreciated!

Comment: perhaps this is a problem with Data which means you have same data in UnitPropertyA and UnitPropertyB

Comment: Thanks @ElyasEsna! I think the cause might be that when filtered include is applied, the result will 'accumulate'.

Answer (score 0):

After searching for answers for almost a day, I think I found the answer. The cause might be that when filtered include is applied within the same db context, the result will 'accumulate'.